# Can we enrich the header as a POJO for RabbitMQ in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am using POJO in header enrichment of RabbitMQ. Can we do like that? After enriching the header will consumer of the queue will get that header? Its configuration is as follows:

```
    <integration:chain input-channel="queeChannel" >
        <integration:header-enricher>
                <integration:header name="myheader" ref="myBean" method="myMethod"></integration:header>
        </integration:header-enricher>
        <integration:recipient-list-router
            apply-sequence="true">
            <integration:recipient channel="mqChannel"/>
        </integration:recipient-list-router>
    </integration:chain>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any non-standard headers must be supplied by `header-mapper` on the `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` (or with `MessagePostProcessor` in case of direct `RabbitTemplate` usage). As well as they should be accepted on the consumer side (`<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter mapped-request-headers="myheader">`).

What is bad it isn't enough. AMQP protocol (as well as any wire protocol) can get deal only with standard object types (`DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter`):

```
 boolean valid = (value instanceof String) || (value instanceof byte[]) || (value instanceof Boolean)
            || (value instanceof LongString) || (value instanceof Integer) || (value instanceof Long)
            || (value instanceof Float) || (value instanceof Double) || (value instanceof BigDecimal)
            || (value instanceof Short) || (value instanceof Byte) || (value instanceof Date)
            || (value instanceof List) || (value instanceof Map);
    if (!valid && value != null) {
        value = value.toString();
    }
```

So, you POJO header will be treated only just like `String`.

So, be sure that your logic is enough convenient.